# Can ForwardIterator and OutputIterator in C++ standard algorithms be the same?

Tags: c++, stl, undefined-behavior

Can the 'streaming' algorithm like `std::transform` or `std::partial_sum` read from and write to the same place?

For example the following code works in gcc but I'm not sure if it is not 'just accident' and compiler is free to break the code in order to optimize it.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  int arr[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  std::vector<int> vec(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
  std::partial_sum(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin());
  for(std::vector<int>::iterator iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); iter++)
    std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this would work fine.  You would overwrite your source for the same amount of answer elements.

For example,

```
int square(int x) { return x*x; }
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), square);
```

Would square each number in vec in their place.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, absolutely, as long as the iterator allows read/write in the first place (for instance, you obviously cannot read from `std::cout`). A common pattern is to use `transform` to mutate a vector in-place.

Comment: For the `partial_sum` example in the question, it seems that the implementation of the algorithm relies on filling up a new vector first, and only then copying its contents to the original `vec`. Otherwise, if the substitutions were done "in place", the first partial sums calculated would replace the original elements of the vector, affecting the next sums, which would result in  `0,1,3,8,17...` instead of the expected `0,1,3,6,10...`.(This would not be a problem in @w00te's example, of course). Does the standard guarantee that it works the right way?

Comment: @Marek I don’t follow. `partial_sum` doesn’t rely on filling up a new vector. The operation can be trivially done in place, and the obvious implementation does exactly that (see e.g. [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/reference/std/numeric/partial_sum/)).

Comment: @Marek Furthermore, the standard actually guarantees this (e.g. §26.4.3.5). And no, you *don’t* have to start from the last index. In fact, *you cannot*: there is no index, the algorithm operates on (non random access) iterators!

Comment: @Kondrad True, you just have to start from the last index :)

Comment: @Marek: What is your platform? gcc 4.6 on Linux produces `0,1,3,6,10...`.

Comment: @Maciej: On my computer it also works fine, just as you say. I was just wondering if another implementation, i.e. to calculate every resulting element "from scratch" (which could lead to errors if the source and destination vectors were the same) was allowed. But that would be a horribly inefficient solution, better to do it e.g. by just storing the sum in a temporary variable. Stupid me :). Also, as Konrad said, the standard states explicitly that the vectors can be the same. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Marek: No problem. I have seen too many code which done such "obviously" correct things as assigning pointer or long to int to prefer to ask even if it seems to work.